Posting New Product on Google Business Profile - Need Guidance
I've encountered a challenge while attempting to post a new product on a Google Business Profile, and I'm seeking guidance on how to proceed. Despite my efforts, I've been unable to find any documentation pertaining to the API required for this task, or instructions on how to push my CSV feed.
My goal is to add a new product to my Google Business Profile, either through direct API integration or by pushing a CSV feed.
However, I've been unable to find any official documentation or resources outlining the necessary steps for accomplishing this task.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Search Efforts: I've thoroughly searched through Google's official documentation, developer forums, and various online resources in an attempt to locate relevant information about posting products to a Google Business Profile. Unfortunately, my search has yielded no results.

API Exploration: I've explored Google's API documentation extensively, including the Google My Business API, but have not found any endpoints or methods specifically related to adding new products.

CSV Feed: Additionally, I've considered the option of pushing a CSV feed to update my Google Business Profile with new product information. However, I couldn't find any documentation or guidelines on how to format and push such a feed.

Could anyone provide guidance, insights, or point me in the right direction? Any links to relevant documentation, tutorials, or personal experiences would be greatly appreciated.
